# Travel to US for medical treatment

Tags: visas, usa, health, medical-tourism

Is an ESTA enough to travel to the USA for medical treatment for the UK Residents?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: you can assume from the question, it's UK

Comment: @kmonsoor No you can't. Residency and citizenship are two *very* different things.

Comment: @JoErNanO yes, you are right. my missed the difference.

Answer (score 3):

If eligible for VWP then Yes: see under Tourism [on the U.S. State Department Visa Waiver Program page](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html), as well as a more detailed [Visitor Visas: Business and Pleasure](http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/VisaFlyer_March_2014_print.pdf) flyer (emphasis added):

> **Pleasure, Tourism, Medical Treatment - Visitor Visas (B-2)**
>   If the purpose of the planned travel is recreational in nature, including tourism, visiting friends or relatives, rest, or is related to **medical treatment**… then a visitor visa (B-2) would be the appropriate type of visa for the travel.…
>
> Travelers coming to the United States for tourism or business (B-1 or B-2 category visa) purposes for 90 days or less from qualified countries* may be eligible to travel without a visa if they meet the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) requirements.